# how to bind click trigger, only to clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some elements having `fbutton` class. How can I bind a click element only to clicked element. I have a code like this:

```
    $('.fbutton').click(function() {

        /*
            Some Code 1
        */
            $(this).next().click();
        /*
            Some Code 2
        */
            enough;
    });
```

`$(this).next().click();` line triggers a click on an element, but also all other `fbutton` elements are triggered too (**this part bothers me**).

First solution that comes to mind is that end script processing after **Some Code 2**. As return; does not work, I used an illegal javascript code that results abnormal end of execution of code. **It works**, but it is not the correct way of ending execution. How can I end javascript execution or How can I trigger an event only for clicked element.

**More Clarification** 
I want only clicked .fbutton to trigger. ***So does jquery identify clicked element?*** Also I can not define any class for any .fbutton element, because trigger should depend on user click.

Comment: It's common practice to use the '$' sign instead of jQuery every time.

Comment: I know, just to be on the safe side, I use jQuery.

Comment: its actually harmful for you to do that because it prevents you from seeing contention (which well-written code does not have). your code will break using `$` if there is contention due to mismanaged plugins or something, which will force you to fix it.

Comment: thanks, But I wonder why Yii framework uses jQuery statement?

Comment: not sure, but i can tell you that `$` works just fine => http://usingjquery.com/2010/10/using-jquery-with-the-yii-framework/

Comment: auto genereted jquery scripts of Yii are written by jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onclick give it a class, and bind the click triggering to it.

```
$('.fbutton').on('click',function() {

    // Code 1

    $(this).hasClass('clicked')) ? $(this).next().trigger('click') : $(this).addClass('clicked');

    // Code 2

});
```

Also, using jQuery vs $? I kept it consistent for you, but if you can use $ I recommend it.

**EDIT**

To clarify my answer:

This is a ternary if statement. It checks to see if the item clicked has a class of `clicked`, and if it does, then it assigns the click you want to `$(this).next()`, but if it doesn't have the class already it adds the class (without binding the click statement yet). When the element is clicked again, it will have class `clicked`, so it should fire then.

This allows you to only have the click event binded to elements that have already been clicked.

**SECOND EDIT**

[Here is a jsFiddle to show it works](http://jsfiddle.net/nfHQ5/4/).

Click example once and nothing will happen but adding the class, click it again and it will trigger the click of the next button, but not anything else. The same is true for the second button, so that you can see they are separate events for each pairing, unrelated to any other button pairs.

Comment: would you please clarify your answer?

Comment: i hope that is enough clarification, but if you require more let me know.

Comment: thanks @PlantTheIdea, But it doesn't work. because this scenario will repeat for all other fbutton elements.

Comment: oh i misunderstood, you want only CERTAIN `.fbutton` elements to trigger this, is that what you mean? because thats not really possible, it'd be easier just to add another class to the specific items you want and trigger the `click` binding based on that other class.

Comment: I want only clicked .fbutton to trigger. So jquery doesn't identify clicked element? Also I can not define any class for any .fbutton element, because trigger should depend on user click.

Comment: enough shenanigans, updated my answer with a jsFiddle to show what I mean. i also rewrote my answer to use the syntax that i prefer (not shorthand).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29253/discussion-between-hpm-and-planttheidea)

Comment: i'm at work bro, take it or leave it. god knows i'm leaving it, if the jsFiddle isn't proof enough for you then i have no idea what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using stopPropagation?

```
$('.fbutton').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).next().trigger('click'); 
});
```